# Adding Support Page to Web Store Extension Page

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to add a support page right in the extension window but all that I can find is adding a link to another page. I've included some pictures, as I don't know how to really describe the feature.

[image]

that's what I have currently, and below is what I want to have-

[image]

This is a screenshot of what I have on the dev page, concerning the support feature-

[image]

I'm not sure what I need to change, so any help would be appreciated! (Directed here from [this chrome forum thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/n788XDcaJDI;context-place=forum/chrome))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard
2. Click "Edit your User Feedback preferences"
3. Check the "Enable User Feedback for all my apps in Chrome Webstore." box.

Note that neither you nor your users will get notified of new posts made in the webstore support section, so you probably want to direct users to a third party support platform, such as issues on the project's Github repo.